# Redirect subdomain to only http, not https

Tags: http, https

I have my main site (turnereison.com) set to be HTTPS, but I want my subdomain (example.turnereison.com) to be HTTP, for a reason I don't want to get into here. Clearing my cache fixes it until I go back to the main site.

Comment: That visiting the main site breaks it again probably points to [a `Strict-Transport-Security` header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) being set by it.

Comment: How would I fix that? I don't see that header being added in the htaccess file, but I'm new at this stuff so I might be missing it. The main site is WordPress if that helps. @ceejayoz

Answer (score 0):

`curl -I turnereison.com` returns a response that includes the following header:

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains
```

This [HTTP Strict Transport Security header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) tells the browser to enforce HTTPS for the entire domain name, including any subdomains. Clearing your cache works because it forgets this setting; when you visit `turnereison.com` again it becomes enforced again.

You'll want to adjust this header to leave out the `includeSubDomains` (although adding HTTPS to the subdomain would be far preferable, and is free with Let's Encrypt). It might be set by [a WordPress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/hsts/), or your server configuration somewhere.